# get error to fill id of current user in laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I want to get id of current user who submit a form. In Controller I use `auth()->id()` to get id of user but I get SQL error that say `Column 'user_id' cannot be null`. What causes this problem? I wrote following code:

```
Post::create([
    'title' => request('title'),
    'body' => request('body'),
     'user_id' => auth()->id()
]);
```

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solved my problem!
I add `user_id` in fillable array in model and the problem to be solve.

`protected $fillable = ['title', 'body', 'user_id'];`

Answer (score 2):

You should use `auth()->user()->id` or `request()->user()->id`

Comment: or using the [Facades](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/authentication#retrieving-the-authenticated-user) Retrieving The Authenticated User
You may access the authenticated user via the Auth facade:

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;

// Get the currently authenticated user...
$user = Auth::user();

// Get the currently authenticated user's ID...
$id = Auth::id();

Comment: I found solution. The problem is `user_id` is not fillable in question code. I add my answer to the answers.